# Move a picture box infinitely within a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pretty new in C#, I am trying to make a ping pong game in Windows Forms Application, I have used a panel and inside that I am using 2 picture boxes one for paddle and another for the Ball. For the Paddle I have simply used an paddle Image and have used the following Forms event for the movement of the paddle:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            if (pictureBox1.Left < panel1.Left)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left -= 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Left -= 5;
            }
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            if (pictureBox1.Right > panel1.Right)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Left += 5;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

which is working finely, and for the ball I have created the graphics to draw the circle as follows:

```
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Circle(e);
}

private void Circle(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g1 = e.Graphics;
    Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.Black);
    g1.DrawEllipse(p1, 4, 4, 18, 18);
}
```

Now the problem is that i am not able to move the Picture Box with the Ball graphics infinitely I have used timer but it still hasn't worked:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some for loop condition to move the Image
   for(;;)
     {
         //some condition to move the image infinitely
     }
}
```

I am not quite sure how to use the timer function to execute the required infinite movement of the picture box inside the panel. I tried to give it a separate thread as well but it won't work.

Comment: I don't think people downvote because someone is a newbie. I would expect people to downvote because of over-generalized error descriptions like "_…it won't work…_".

Comment: Within your tick event you have to move the box just one step and leave the function again. If you then set the timer interval to eg. 50 ms you should see the desired movement.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thanks...

Comment: @Oliver so do i need to add a time sleep function to it..

Comment: No. The tick event will be called frequently. You have to specify the interval only in the timer interval property in milliseconds. Within that event you only do `pictureBoxBall.Left += 5`.

Comment: ok understood, thanks will try this......

Comment: Yup, it worked, thanks for the tip @Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as suggested by Oliver from the comments section I added a timer interval to the tick event as follows:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = 15;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBoxBall.Left += 5;
    }
```

Thanks for the solution.